# Paraview cannot SaveScreenshot when there are two Views - append_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_seq_number' failed

Tags: python, screenshot, paraview

I am under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I am using `ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvpython`, simply expanded from `ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit.tar.gz`

I have a python script to:

1. Generate a RenderView from a PVD reader.
2. SaveScreenshot.
3. PlotOverLine from the RenderView.
4. SaveScreenshot.

The script crashes when run from `pvpython`, but it works when run as a macro from the UI.
The error message is

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while appending request
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
pvpython: ../../src/xcb_io.c:161: append_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_seq_number' failed.
```

**How can I make this work?**

Adding the `EXTRA LINES` (see code below) the error goes away.
I still have to tune the parameters of `lineChartView1.ViewSize` and `ImageResolution` to get a proper `png`, but I trust that will work.
Nevertheless, I mean to not need removing one View to make it work.

---

A minimalistic version of the script (with many lines from the Trace removed) is:

```
from paraview.simple import *
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

# 1. Generate a RenderView from a PVD reader.
pvdreader = PVDReader(FileName='mydata.pvd')
animationScene1 = GetAnimationScene()
animationScene1.UpdateAnimationUsingDataTimeSteps()
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
renderView1.ViewSize = [1554, 838]
pvdreaderDisplay = Show(pvdreader, renderView1)
renderView1.ResetCamera()
renderView1.Update()
layout1 = GetLayout()
# 2. SaveScreenshot.
SaveScreenshot('last_frame_render.png', renderView1, ImageResolution=[1554, 838])
# 3. PlotOverLine from the RenderView.
plotOverLine1 = PlotOverLine(Input=pvdreader, Source='High Resolution Line Source')
plotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [-5.0, -5.0, 0.0]
plotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [5.0, 5.0, 0.0]
plotOverLine1Display = Show(plotOverLine1, renderView1)
lineChartView1 = CreateView('XYChartView')
layout1.AssignView(2, lineChartView1)
plotOverLine1Display_1 = Show(plotOverLine1, lineChartView1)
# ==========================  EXTRA LINES  ==============================
# destroy renderView1
Delete(renderView1)
del renderView1
layout1.Collapse(1)
# =======================================================================
lineChartView1.ViewSize = [1554, 838]
lineChartView1.Update()
# 4. SaveScreenshot.
SaveScreenshot('last_frame_linechart.png', lineChartView1, ImageResolution=[772, 838])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the [differences between `pvpython` and `pvbatch`](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView_and_Batch) are:

1. `pvbatch` cannot run interactively.
2. `pvbatch` supports parallel processing.

I used
`ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvbatch` instead of
`ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvpython` and it worked.

I do not know if there is a better or alternative solution.